# CSS Reponsive Form Design Issue

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am hoping someone can give me a hand with the CSS for a form.
It looks good at 320px wide and 720px wide, but when I get to 968px wide I can't quite figure out how to fix it. Here is a screen shot of how it looks and how I would like it to look. The way that it is now, the last three elements are to the right, but it is not aligning to the top of the form. Here is the url of the page http://rat-pack.com/new/contact.php Here is the url of the css file http://rat-pack.com/new/css/contactform.css
[image]

Here is the form html and css...

```css
    #ContactForm {
    width:98%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding:.3125em;
    border: 1px solid #000040;
    border-radius:.5em;
    color:#ffffff;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #808080;
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    text-align:left;
    padding:.3125em;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    #FormFrame {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    } 
 
    #FormFrame ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 1.25em 0 0;
    font-size: .9375em; 
    line-height: 1;
    color:#000000;
    }

    #FormFrame li {
    padding: 0 0 .625em;
    font-size: .9375em; 
    line-height: 1;
    color:#000000;
    }

    #FormFrame legend {
    font-size: .9375em; 
    line-height: 1;
    }

    label {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.25;
    padding: 0 0 .3125em;
    font-size: .9375em; 
    line-height: 1;
    color:#000000;
    }


    select, input, textarea {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: .9375em;
    color:#000000;
    line-height: 1;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: .625em;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }


    textarea {
    padding-bottom: 5%;
    overflow: auto; /* 1 */
    vertical-align: top; /* 2 */
    }

    .ValCode {
    color:#004000;
    font-family:times;
    font-style:italic;
    font-size:1em;
    font-weight:bold;
    }  

    .send {
    border-radius:.25em;
    border-color:#d8d8d8;
    border-width:.09375em;
    background-color:#004000;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding:.25em;
    }


    .send:hover {
    background: #002000;
    color:#f0f0f0;
    }

    .send:active,
    .send:focus {
    background: #001000;
    color:#d8d8d8;
    }    



    @media screen and (min-width: 45em) {

    .name {
    padding-right: .625em;
    float: left;
    width: 48%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .email {
    padding-left: .625em;
    float: right;
    width: 48%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }
 
    .message {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .validation {
    float: left;
    width: 48%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .SendButton {
    margin-top:1.25em;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    float: right;
    width: 48%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    }


    @media screen and (min-width: 60.5em) 
    {

    #FormFrame {
    vertical-align:top;
    }

    .SendTo, .name, .email {
    display:block;
    padding-right: .3125em;
    float: left;
    width: 48%;
    clear:left;
    }

    .message, .validation, .SendButton {
    display:block;
    padding-left: .3125em;
    float: right;
    width: 48%;
    clear:right;
    }
 
    }
```

```html
<form id="ContactForm" name="ContactForm" method="post" action="Contact.php" title="Contact T.R.A.P., T.T.T or CMC">
    <fieldset id="FormFrame">
    <ul>
    <li class="SendTo" title="Select who you are contacting">
    <label for="SendTo">Send To</label>
    <select name="SendTo">
    <option value="CMC Sales" title="CMC Sales">Sales</option>
    <option value="CMC Parts" title="CMC Parts">Parts</option>
    <option value="CMC Service" title="CMC Service">Service</option>
    </select>
    </li>
    <li class="name" title="Enter your name">
    <label for="YourName">Your Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="YourName" name="YourName" />
    </li>
    <li class="email" title="Enter your email address">
    <label for="YourEmail">Your Email</label>
    <input type="email" id="YourEmail" name="YourEmail" />
    </li>
    <li class="message" title="Enter your message">
    <label for="TheMessage">Say Something</label>
    <textarea id="TheMessage" name="TheMessage"></textarea>
    </li>
    <li class="validation" title="Enter the validation code">
    <label for="TC" id="LockedEl">Validation Code: <span class="ValCode"><?PHP echo $ShowTC ?></span></label>
    <input type="text" name="TC" size="6" value="" class="breg">
    </li>
    <li class="SendButton">
    <input class="send" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send It"  title="Send your email" />
    </li>
    </ul>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Comment: You should post the actual code so people can see how elements are set out. It would also be a good idea to put the CSS straight into SO so it will **always** be here for reference

Comment: if you are going in this route then do 2 ul that will put them in 2 columns...

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Here is the form html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what's happening here is that your `float:right` elements are starting their float *after* your block of `float:left` elements -- so, this is expected behavior, but I understand that it's not what you are going for. If you're not concerned with maintaining the exact order of elements you had in your example, you can replace your media queries with the following CSS and things will lay out more neatly :

```
@media screen and (min-width: 45em) and (max-width:60.49em) {
  .name,
  .email,
  .validation,
  .SendButton {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 49%;
  }
  .name,
  .validation {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1%;
  }
  .email,
  .SendButton {
    float: right;
  }
  .SendButton {
    margin-top: 1.25em;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 60.5em) {
  #FormFrame li {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 49%;
  }
  #FormFrame li:nth-child(odd) {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1%;
  }
  #FormFrame li:nth-child(even) {
    float: right;
  }
}
```

Otherwise, you'll need to wrap each section (one for send to, your name, your email; another for the textarea, validation code and button) and apply the width and float to those div columns. Up to you to decide if the extra markup is worth it.

```css
#ContactForm {
  width: 98%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: .3125em;
  border: 1px solid #000040;
  border-radius: .5em;
  color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #808080;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  text-align: left;
  padding: .3125em;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#FormFrame {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#FormFrame ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 1.25em 0 0;
  font-size: .9375em;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #000000;
}
#FormFrame li {
  padding: 0 0 .625em;
  font-size: .9375em;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #000000;
}
#FormFrame legend {
  font-size: .9375em;
  line-height: 1;
}
label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.25;
  padding: 0 0 .3125em;
  font-size: .9375em;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #000000;
}
select,
input,
textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: .9375em;
  color: #000000;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: .625em;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
textarea {
  padding-bottom: 5%;
  overflow: auto;
  /* 1 */
  vertical-align: top;
  /* 2 */
}
.ValCode {
  color: #004000;
  font-family: times;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.send {
  border-radius: .25em;
  border-color: #d8d8d8;
  border-width: .09375em;
  background-color: #004000;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: .25em;
}
.send:hover {
  background: #002000;
  color: #f0f0f0;
}
.send:active,
.send:focus {
  background: #001000;
  color: #d8d8d8;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 45em) and (max-width: 60.49em) {
  .name,
  .email,
  .validation,
  .SendButton {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 49%;
  }
  .name,
  .validation {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1%;
  }
  .email,
  .SendButton {
    float: right;
  }
  .SendButton {
    margin-top: 1.25em;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 60.5em) {
  #FormFrame li {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 49%;
  }
  #FormFrame li:nth-child(odd) {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1%;
  }
  #FormFrame li:nth-child(even) {
    float: right;
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="ContactForm" name="ContactForm" method="post" action="Contact.php" title="Contact T.R.A.P., T.T.T or CMC">
  <fieldset id="FormFrame">
    <ul>
      <li class="SendTo" title="Select who you are contacting">
        <label for="SendTo">Send To</label>
        <select name="SendTo">
          <option value="CMC Sales" title="CMC Sales">Sales</option>
          <option value="CMC Parts" title="CMC Parts">Parts</option>
          <option value="CMC Service" title="CMC Service">Service</option>
        </select>
      </li>
      <li class="name" title="Enter your name">
        <label for="YourName">Your Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="YourName" name="YourName" />
      </li>
      <li class="email" title="Enter your email address">
        <label for="YourEmail">Your Email</label>
        <input type="email" id="YourEmail" name="YourEmail" />
      </li>
      <li class="message" title="Enter your message">
        <label for="TheMessage">Say Something</label>
        <textarea id="TheMessage" name="TheMessage"></textarea>
      </li>
      <li class="validation" title="Enter the validation code">
        <label for="TC" id="LockedEl">Validation Code: <span class="ValCode"><?PHP echo $ShowTC ?></span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="TC" size="6" value="" class="breg">
      </li>
      <li class="SendButton">
        <input class="send" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send It" title="Send your email" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer gave me clue to what I needed to do.